# how to connect to wifi on ubuntu server 10.10

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-server

i will be installing ubuntu server and since its all through terminal how do i connect to wifi?

what commands do i type in to connect and enter the passsword?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The configuration is all done through the /etc/network/interfaces file.

You need to have something like this in your /etc/network/interfaces file:

*(this is for a WPA2 encrypted network)*

```
auto wlan0

iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-driver wext
    wpa-ssid AccessPointName
    wpa-ap-scan 2
    wpa-proto RSN
    wpa-pairwise CCMP
    wpa-group CCMP
    wpa-key-mgmt WPA-PSK
    wpa-psk <your_hex_key>
```

Where `<your_hex_key>` is obtained by using:

```
# wpa_passphrase "Access Point Name" "WPA2 Pass Phrase"
```

You can change the network to use "static" instead of "dhcp" if you want to use a static IP address.  You can then specify something like this:

```
address 192.168.1.44
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

in the main block of configuration.

Comment: the command auto didnt work for me for "auto wlan0" and iface didnt work as well. and i dont have /etc/network/interfaces its a fresh install of ubuntu-server do i need to connect to eth0 and download a bunch of files before going on wifi?

Comment: if /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist then just create it.  Auto and Iface aren't commands - they are configuration instructions you put into the /etc/network/interfaces file.

Comment: wpa_passphrase is the only command you type at a terminal (hence the # prompt infront of it - # = root's prompt)